# What is the best way to light an interior scene in Blender Eevee without baking indirect lighting?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I am working on a scene for a fan film and we are having to use the Eevee render engine because of a shader that is being applied to materials. I am stuck on how to light interior scenes, I have attached an example below which I should exemplify my issue.

If I use area lights then the ceiling will be dark and their will be a very obvious cut off line. If I use point lights then I get glares/reflections on the ceiling.

Ive been told by the animation team that I cant bake the indirect lighting because it will cause issues with animation, does anyone know the best method for lighting interior scenes in eevee?

[image]

-Area lights

[image]

- Point lights

Any help or known tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the question is more opinion based (maybe rephrase the title?), but I would be interested in answers as well.

Comment: You can put a weak arealight against the ceiling to light it up. But I'm not a pro in rendering. There are a few demo file for EEVEE on the official website. Check them out. May be you can append something useful of them for example world or lighting, or the settings also can be helpful. https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/#eevee